# Troubling when knit

Tags: r, knitr, rlang

I have a trouble when i knit the files, how should i do to solve this problem? I already remove packages rlang and reinstall rlang, but it is not work

Microsoft R Open 4.0.2
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2020 Microsoft Corporation

Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 2 cores).

Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2020-07-16.
See: https://mran.microsoft.com/.

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace 'rlang' 0.4.6 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
Calls: :: ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
```

Comment: You should use the current version of R from CRAN, not a version of R from 2020.

Comment: @user2554330 what are the steps to use the current version of R from CRAN?

Comment: Download it from one of the links at `cloud.r-project.org`, and install it.  Which one depends on your OS, but it looks like you're using Windows, so that would be https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/ .